# Does anyone know which deity this is?

Tags: shiva, gods, identification-request

Need help identifying the deity in the below image. I’m thinking this is image of Shiva sitting in the cremation grounds?

[image]

Comment: It is easily Shiva

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]

This is certainly an image of Lord Shiva , who is  one among the triad gods (Brahma-Vishnu-Shiva).

This is well conformed when we look at it. It clearly shows some distinct features of Lord Shiva as we know from his description from scriptures like

- Trident  and Damaru (a musical instrument) in his hand.
- Crescent moon on his head.
- A third eye on his forehead.
- Rudraksha on wrist and around neck.
- Snakes wrapped  around neck.

We can also see the Shiva- Lingas on the side of the image which further confirms that its Shiva.

---

**A little description about painting and painter.**

Quick [**reverse image search**](https://www.buddhistdoor.net/features/reflections-on-learning-to-paint-like-a-medieval-thangka-painter-hand-grinding-gems-and-minerals-into-pigment)  takes us  to the original source of the Image and it's artist.

This is a painting drawn by well known Nepali artist  Sudarshan Suwal. He is renowned  thangka painter.
In Thangka  method  paintings are painted by ground mineral paints with hand.He paints images of  the tantric practices of Kashmir Shaivism with those from the Vajrayana Buddhist tradition.

So **this is Tantrik Image of Lord shiva  painted in Buddhist and Hindu iconography in thangka style** and mostly related to Kashmir Shaivism.

Comment: good one...u can add "snakes" also in "It clearly shows some distinct features"...

Comment: @YDS - Thanks edited the answer with mention of snakes and one more imp. point which i missed.  is  rudraksha around wrist

Comment: Thanks that is very helpful I thought it was Shiva just not like the other depictions I’ve seen.

Comment: Well, if you analyze the picture, the deity has damaru in his right arm, trishul in his left arm, has crescent moon on his head, wearing the vyaghracharma, wearing a serpent necklace, sitting on a Srichakra, and also has the third eye!  Also in the background there is Shivaling depictions and several animals playing(Pashupati). All these are indicative of Shiva.

Comment: @ColinBondi, if you did find the answer helpful and satisfactory, you may want to accept the answer by clicking the tick button below the voting arrows. If you do like the answer (and haven’t already), you may give it an upvote too. That’s how the community knows that this is the correct answer. Thanks :)